# How to disable autocompleet intellisence when pressing spacebar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, intellisense

While creating test in vb.net i found it pretty annoying when you start typing and autocompleet changes a class to something similar looking even it is a class you don't want.

Image to illustrate : 
[image: Controller not created yet]

In the picture you can see I am trying to setup a controller (this controller does not exist at the moment) so when i press the spacebar i will get DienstControllerFacts.

How do you disable this sort of auto-correction?

Comment: I think I've just gotten used to hitting esc then space, that'll probably annoy me now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your image, but I think [this gives you some keyboard shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exbffbc2.aspx) for dealing with your issue, and [this shows you how to modify the settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to selecting Common tab instead of All tab in the intellisense window?